# BOX web application integrations error

Tags: box-api, box

I'm integrating Box app with my website follow this guide https://developers.box.com/box-web-application-integrations/

My Box App allow Box's user to upload selected file directly from Box to my Website via Rest API with method POST, so I set the POST upload API url in the Preliminary Callback URL of app setting (The API is working so far with no problem). But i got error from box is `Your Box account may be temporarily unavailable. We're working on resolving the issue and should be back up soon.` I don't know what is exactly the root cause in  this case.

In Callback Parameters Section

- POST | file_name | #file_name#
- File | file | the file selected by the user

Very appreciated if you have any idea for this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem?

Comment: Hi @JohnHoerr, Yes it seem that there is issue with POST method. So that I have to change to GET method and use Box JAVA SDK  to download the file in Back-end. Detail for that https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/issues/172